# Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load()

Tags: 7

I deleted the user uid 1 and successively I created another user as admin.
Now appeared a number of errors like these:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load() (line 3641 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3641 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load() (line 3642 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3642 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load() (line 3643 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3643 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load() (line 3641 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3641 of /mysite/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in user_node_load() (line 3642 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3642 of /mysite/modules/user/user.module).
```

This user.module code.

```
  // Add these values back into the node objects.
  foreach ($uids as $nid => $uid) {
    $nodes[$nid]->name = $user_fields[$uid]->name;
    $nodes[$nid]->picture = $user_fields[$uid]->picture;
    $nodes[$nid]->data = $user_fields[$uid]->data;
  }
```

Can u help me?

Comment: You should never delete user 1. Even if you create another user with Admin role is not going to be the same. Some rule looks for uid 1.

Comment: thx Durden but anyone have hacker my site and cancel my admin account.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Best this would be to restore from a previous back up. Have you tried to recreate it manually?

Comment: The issue is handled in [Warnings in user_node_load() for deleted users](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2653342).

Answer (score 0):

I have change uid to 1 of new admin user in database and all sound good.

Comment: Now you should review all security concerns of your site to prevent from hackers.